# How to get a XMLText Value returned by Ezpublish Rest API converted to HTML5 in advance?

Tags: xml, html, rest, ezpublish

I would like to get XMLText field values returned by Ezpublish Rest API in HTML5 format instead of Internal XML format

Which will be a simple way to do it ?

Kind Regards

Comment: I have looked at the XMLText field Rest API PHP code, but haven't found answer there, maybe I should try to convert to HTML 5 on the client, for instance using Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't implemented, and it might not be. XmlText is being replaced with RichText. Given the focus on Platform, it is for now not planned to improve XmlText support, even though active demand from users can always do a difference.

In the meantime, the easiest thing would be to write your own custom REST API endpoint, either using the repository's API framework, or using your own controllers. It would use the same code that is used internally to do the conversion, meaning that it wouldn't be much work.